# Create hardware specific key from any web browser

Tags: javascript, security

We currently have a web browser application that runs only under Internet explorer that we are trying to make cross browser. The main reason for using IE is that we can access the hardware information from an ActiveX control. We would like to get away from this methodology for obvious reasons.

If we forget about the way things are currently being done and go back to the security requirements and look for other ways to accomplish the same thing. The user of the application must be on a known computer that must be in a secure location. I am at a loss on how to do this.

We currently use Protect/unprotect to encrypt the data we need and guarantee that the file can only be decrypted on the same machine. This keeps the user from finding the file and copying it to another machine and running. The file is put on the computer by a separate installation process that can only be run by authorized personnel.

So how do I get a machine specific key of some type that allows me to identify the computer with no chance of being replicated to another computer?

====================================

We are trying to do exactly what the web is trying to keep us from doing, so this may not be doable without specific browser extensions, such as a ActiveXControl.

The USB response is interesting but it does not guarantee location. We do use USB devices for terminals that require 2 factor authentication.

The other possibility is a user or machine certificate installed in the computer. The problem I see with that is the certificate can be exported. We had tried this years ago and the operational overhead was too high.

Comment: I've seen this done with USB devices on chrome, when the device is connected a chrome extension would detect the device and authorize access to certain pages by sending limited time tokens with each request, the device is polled every few seconds, and if it's ever removed the pages are closed. I could see if it's possible for me to find the code if that sounds like it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Good luck with that. We tried this path in the past, but we got no decent cross-browser result. Even working with Chrome only, which lets Javascript access to many hardware goodies, didn't lead to an acceptable experience, since it actually asks for permissions for everything. And it's actually a good thing, since the user *must* be in control of what hardware a page tries to access. I'm starring this question anyway, for the sake of curiosity about what people here may answer or comment.